# Intuition of definition of degree of function $\deg(f)=\widetilde f(1)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition

> Definition. Let $f:(I,\mathring I)\to(S^1,1)$ be a continuous function, the degree of the function $f$ is defined by $$\deg(f)=\widetilde{f}(1)$$
>
> where $\widetilde f$ is the unique lifting of $f$ with $\widetilde f(0)=0.$

$\widetilde f$ is such that $\exp\circ\widetilde f=f.$

Could someone please explain  what this definition means intuitively?

I have a lot of exercises that involve this definition and I do not see any idea on how to solve them, perhaps with the intuition of this definition would help me.

Thank you.

I did read the answer of the question
[What does the degree of a loop in $S^1$ means *intuitively?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285059/what-does-the-degree-of-a-loop-in-s1-means-intuitively) in which the definition is different and got the idea.

Comment: Actually, the definition in [the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285059/what-does-the-degree-of-a-loop-in-s1-means-intuitively) is exactly the same, it is just stated more tersely and in greater generality. Where it says "let $\tilde p$ be a lift of $p$", what that means is that $\tilde p$ is such that $\operatorname{exp} \circ \tilde p = p$.

Comment: @LeeMosher How is that they are equal if they defined degree as the difference $\tilde p(1) - \tilde p(0)$ ?

Comment: As I said, that one is a generalization of the one in your question. Your question specifies that $\tilde f(0)=0$, and therefore $\tilde f(1) - \tilde f(0) = \tilde f(1) - 0 = \tilde f(1)$.